# Slow Access to smb Files and Directories from MS office - Excel VBA

Tags: windows, excel, smb, excel-2013, vba

I am running MS Office 2013, and I'm trying to list files in an smb directory from Excel VBA code.

```
unix_path = "\\smb" & unix_path

 ListBox3.Clear
 Dim fil As file
 On Error Resume Next
 If Dir(unix_path, vbDirectory) <> "" Then

 Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
 Set mysource = MyObject.GetFolder(unix_path)
 For Each myFile In mysource.Files
 If InStr(myFile.Name, ".xlsx") > 0 Then
    UserForm1.ListBox3.AddItem myFile.Name
End If
```

This takes about 15 seconds. The directory itself has only 5 files in it.
It is worth mentioning that accessing the directory directly from explorer is much faster (less than 1 second).

Comment: When you try to step through the code, does it hang on the Dir call? or a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FSO has a lot of overhead from my experience and I have experienced some odd issues over our network with it.  I do not frequently use it unless I am doing something more specific than this situation.

Please test the following code and see if it still hangs,

```
unix_path = "\\smb" & unix_path

 ListBox3.Clear
 Dim fil As file
 On Error Resume Next
 If Dir(unix_path, vbDirectory) <> "" Then

 mySource = Dir(unix_path & "*.xlsx")
 Do until mySource = ""
    UserForm1.ListBox3.AddItem mySource
    mySource = Dir()
 loop
 end if
```

Comment: what a difference. Thanks!